# Using MeCab plugin in MySQL

Tags: mysql, search, japanese, localization

I'm trying to set up the MeCab fulltext search plugin for MySQL (5.7.17) on Ubuntu (16.04). However it's missing the libpluginmecab.so file, which is [apparently](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1576563) "intentionally missing". I have MeCab, libmecab2 and libmecab-dev installed, so how do I get this working with MySQL?

**Edit**
Since then I managed to acquire libpluginmecab.so from the MySQL community server package, but now it refuses to see the MeCab config file. Getting "/etc/mecabrc not found", while the file is there and readable.

Comment: Installation guide: http://www.denbun.com/en/help/helppop.v3/systemadmin/linuxmecab.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's specifically the "connecting MeCab to MySQL " that doesn't work, so your link doesn't help much.